# Connecting outside database via WEB API's to SPO

Tags: external-content-type, api

Has anyone been able to automate a connection to an outside source that uses WEB API's?

We use Deltek Vision in the cloud, and would like to be able to automate some information to carry over from our Deltek database into SharePoint.

I have managed to get a connection via an External Content Type, however beyond that the setup just doesn't seem right.

This is what I get, but there aren't normal parameters that I would expect to see. As shown in the 2nd picture.

Anyone have any experience with this?

[parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2qFf.jpg)
[image: parameters]